# What is the fastest way in R to calculate rolling max with a variable rolling window size?

Tags: r

I have 2 numeric vectors, one stores values to calculate maximum from, another lengths of a rolling window to calculate those maximums on a rolling basis. Below is some sample code. Generally I'm trying to speed up the code inside system.time. Is there some ready function or vectorized way to do the same thing?

```
a <- rep(1:5,20000)
set.seed(123)
b <- rep(sample(1:50),2000)

system.time({
out <- vector(mode='numeric', length=NROW(a))
for(i in seq(a)) {
  if (i-b[i]>=0) out[i] <- max(a[(i-b[i]+1):i])
  else out[i] <- NA
}
})
```

Comment: +1 Good question. This is an interesting problem to try and optimise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to vectorize parts of it:

Original -

```
system.time({
  out <- vector(mode='numeric', length=NROW(a))
  for(i in seq(a)) {
    if (i-b[i]>=0) out[i] <- max(a[(i-b[i]+1):i])
    else out[i] <- NA
  }
})
## user  system elapsed 
## 0.64    0.00    0.64
```

Slightly vectorized -

```
system.time({
  nr <- NROW(a)
  out <- rep(NA,nr)
  m <- 1:nr - b + 1
  n <- (1:nr)[m>0]

  for(i in n)
    out[i] <- max(a[m[i]:i])
})
## user  system elapsed 
## 0.39    0.00    0.39
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorise the parts of this problem, especially where you need to find out the starting index position in `a` (I called this `str`) and the end of the window ( `end` ), but I have to use a looping construct to apply those index positions to `a` to take the `max` using `mapply`. Like so:

```
x <- seq_len( length(a) )
end <- which( x-b > 0 )
str <- end - b[end]
res <- a
res[ - end ] <- NA
res[end] <- mapply( function(x,y) max( a[ x:y ] ) , str , end )
```

And comparing with @e4e5f4 's answer:

```
identical( res , out )
[1] TRUE
```

However it's not *quite* as fast:

```
user  system elapsed 
0.46    0.00    0.47
```

If there was a way to vectorise the last operation then this would be really fast, but I can't think of any way to do this at the moment!